# How to add marker to last data point in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to marker only the last data point?

here is my code

```
def generateLines(XData, YData):
    X = XData
    Y = YData
    lineData = np.vstack((X, Y))
    return lineData

def updateLines(num, dataLines, lines):
    for u, v in zip(lines, dataLines):
        u.set_data(v[0:2, :num])
    return lines
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = [generateLines(XData, YData)]
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-40, 40), ylim=(-250, 250))
```

full code:
[image]

Note: I use the img for full image becauseI cant write full code here

Comment: Are you not importing any modules for this code? numpy and matplotlib for example?

Comment: I import numpy and matplotlib, but I not including in my question

Comment: Struggling to get your program working, do you have a requirements.txt file with the necessary packages or a GitHub link?